# How to add template to kendo-chart-series-item-label in kendo-chart-series?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am trying to add template to kendo-chart-series-item-labels.
I have used similar example from this link: https://plnkr.co/edit/eICeHxnl0JoIwuRYyRSt?p=preview

In app.components.ts file, instead of having this method:

```
public labelContent(e: any): string {
        return `${ e.category }: \n ${e.value}%`;
    }
```

Can i have a template in the element itself? Example:

```
<kendo-chart-series-item-labels
                                  color="gray"
                                  position="outsideEnd"
                                  template="#= category # - #= kendo.format('{0:P}', percentage)#"
                                  align="column"
                                  background="none">
```

this template is not working. So my question is how to write template to display the values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is (currently) no way to set a template directly within the `kendo-chart-series-item-labels` element. But there are 3 alternatives which can be used.

**Option A** - format string

If you 'only' want to properly format the number(s) shown, you can utilize the `format` input, which works for all kinds of [number formats](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-intl/blob/master/docs/num-formatting/index.md#types-of-number-formats).

```
<kendo-chart-series-item-labels [format]="'n2'">
</kendo-chart-series-item-labels>
```

**Option B** - content callback

This is what you already did in the example you linked. Basically you provide a `function` to the chart, which specifies how the label shall look like.

```
<kendo-chart-series-item-labels [content]="contentString">
</kendo-chart-series-item-labels>

public contentString(content) {
    // return the formatted label as a string
}
```

**Option C** - visual content callback

Very similar to *Option B* but instead of returning a string that should be displayed, you are returning a `kendo-drawing` element.

```
<kendo-chart-series-item-labels [visual]="contentVisual">
</kendo-chart-series-item-labels>

public contentVisual(content: SeriesLabelsVisualArgs) {
    // return the formatted label as a kendo-drawing-element
}
```

*Detailed explanation on those options can be found on [their website](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/chart/elements/labels/#toc-customizing-the-content).*